# Insert table inside UWP RichEditBox

Tags: c#, uwp

I need to insert a table inside a RichEditBox in UWP. There doesn't seem to be a valid method to do it. I couldn't find any methods. Does anybody know how to do it?

Comment: Why do you need to insert a table into RichEditBox? It should just be used to handle rich content.

Comment: It seems like rich text files do recognize tables as valid content, so I want to see if it can be done with UWP

Comment: I could load an RTF string to the `RichEditBox` as a table and it works. Could you please tell me what's the behavior you want to get? Just load pure string to the `RichEditBox`? or it is acceptable to load it from an RTF string?

Comment: I want it to be somehow editable, if it's possible. For example, upon insertion, to choose the amount of rows and columns with a numeric box

Comment: Ok, so you want something like a button, click it and you can insert table into the RichEditBox and you could want to control the rows and columns?

Comment: Yes, basically that.

Comment: Have you checked my answer?

Comment: Yes, I have upvoted it. i am testing something and then I will mark it as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to insert Table into `RichEditBox`. The only way is to load RTF strings in the `RichEditBox`.

A simple RTF string looks like this. This represent a table with one row and three columns.

```
 {\rtf1\ansi\deff0
\trowd
\cellx1000
\cellx2000
\cellx3000
cell 1\intbl\cell
cell 2\intbl\cell
cell 3\intbl\cell
\row
}
```

Each **row** begins with `\trowd` and ends with `\row`. Within a row are cells which end with `\cell`.

If you need to add more rows, then you will need to add more `row` blocks into the RTF string. I've made a simple demo about how to insert table RTF. Please refer to the following code:

```
  private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string tableRTF = createTableString(3, 3);

        MyRichBox.Document.SetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.FormatRtf, tableRTF);
    }


    public string createTableString(int row,int column) 
    {

        //Since too much string appending go for string builder
        StringBuilder sringTableRtf = new StringBuilder();

        //beginning of rich text format,dont customize this begining line
        sringTableRtf.Append(@"{\rtf1\ansi\deff0");

        //Loop to populate the table cell data from DataTable
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            //Start the Row
            sringTableRtf.Append(@"\trowd");
            //set cell width and position
            for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
            {
               int cellWidth = (j + 1) * 1000;
                //A cell with width 1000.
                sringTableRtf.Append(@"\cellx"+cellWidth.ToString()+" ");
            }
            //set cell content
            for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
            {
                //give cell a default value as j+1
                sringTableRtf.Append((j+1).ToString()+ @"\intbl\cell ");
            }

            //Insert data row
            sringTableRtf.Append(@"\row");
        }

        sringTableRtf.Append(@"}");

        //convert the string builder to string
        return sringTableRtf.ToString();

    }
```

The result looks like:
[image]

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your response it helped me. But now I have one issue with table resizing. If you know how to fix it, please help me. So I have RichEditBox with TextWrapping NoWrap so the horizontal rail in scroll view is activating when text is wider than the width of the control. Then you can resize the table column width if you pull the edge of it and if this column overcomes the width of control you can scroll inside it. But for some reason, the very right corner is never visible to the user in RichEditBox. Can you suggest me some fix?